# Visual Studio Cordova OS X or IOS Remote connection

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio Cordova to build IOS app remote build or debug feature.

I tried to connect remote server with secure and non secure method and getting different error.

First i generated certificate and use Host IP(Mac IP), security PIN and  IOS device Support Folder details in Visual Studio > Tools > Tool for Apache Cordova > IOS Configuration.

Mac IP = got from ifconfig can be see in attached image.

Security PIN = Genrated by command "*remotebuild certificates generate*"

ISO Device Folder = 192.168.169.130\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Platforms\iPhoneOS.platform\DeviceSupport.

1. [when tried with secure method. Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF6Ut.png)
2. [when tried with secure false method. Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYo6X.png)
3. [started the server by remotebuild. Image Attached](http://www.imagecross.com/d/image-hosting-view-08.php?id=7173OS-X.png)
4. [RemoteBuild test passed. Image Attached](http://www.imagecross.com/d/image-hosting-view-08.php?id=8588RemoteBuild-test-pass.png)

Comment: I hosted Mac on VMware same machine where Visual Studio cordova exsists. IP of Visual Studio machine is like 100.100.**.** and MAC IP is 192.168.**.**

Comment: If you open `https://<ip address of Mac>:3000` in your web browser on the Mac, what message do you see? Can you access that same address from your PC running Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

First, please ensure you've followed the steps mentioned in http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/

And ensure the remotebuild is started on you Mac.

Second, ensure you can successfully ping the ip of your Mac using ping 192.168.x.x

And from the IPs provided, you may run into the issue mentioned in ["Did you receive an error that relates to your certificate?"](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#certificate).

Comment: I followed steps mentioned in Taco docs for IOS.Remotebuild test is passed attach that image description. Yes i can ping both way from window to Mac and Mac to windows. No Certificate error.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the certificates error: In secure mode, you have not set up certificates correctly. On the Mac, you can re-set up your certificates. Close remotebuild using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Enter on the command line:

1. remotebuild certificates reset (When prompted, type <kbd>Y</kbd> and then type <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. remotebuild certificates generate

Then enter the new pin in VS and connect.